# How does my list become ObservedList? Problem with replit db

Tags: python, database, discord.py, replit

I have a problem with making discord bot on repl.it, my list is 'ObservedList' and i dont know what to do with this, when I watch some tutorials its always just a normal list

```
from replit import db

db['fruits'] = ['apple','banana']
print(db['fruits'])
```

Output:

```
ObservedList(value=['apple', 'banana'])
```

Answer (score 3):

When poking around in the link provided in the previous answer, I found some interesting things in the __init__ function.

```
def __init__(
    self, on_mutate: Callable[[List], None], value: Optional[List] = None
) -> None:
    self._on_mutate_handler = on_mutate
    if value is None:
        self.value = []
    else:
        self.value = value
```

If you want to get the list in an ObserverdList called foo, use foo.value to do so.

For example:

```
Output = [“Apple”, “Banana”] + db[“foo”].value
```

Assuming the ObservedList in db[“foo”] is just [“Cantaloupe”], the return would be`[“Apple”]`

Answer (score 2):

`ObservedList` is a class in the [replit package](https://pypi.org/project/replit/)

As stated [in the docstring](https://github.com/replit/replit-py/blob/fc47b96202667ca8a04827285a19e94912bdca29/src/replit/database/database.py#L236) it is

> A list that calls a function every time it is mutated.

There is also `ObservedDict` class.

There is [this tutorial](https://github.com/replit/replit-py/blob/fc47b96202667ca8a04827285a19e94912bdca29/docs/db_tutorial.rst) that shed some more light in Advanced Usage section at the bottom:

> Another problem you might encounter is related to the mutation
> feature. **Under the hood, this feature works by replacing the primitive
> list and dict classes with special replacements that listen for
> mutation, namely replit.database.database.ObservedList and
> replit.database.ObservedDict.**
>
> To JSON encode these values, use the replit.database.dump method. For
> JSON responses in the web framework, this is done automatically.
>
> **To convert these classes to their primitive equivalent, access the
> value attribute. A function that automatically does this is provided:
> replit.database.to_primitive.**
>
> To avoid this behavior entirely, use the get_raw and set_raw methods
> instead.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are asking the bot to print the entire list. If you change your code to:

```
print(db['fruits'][0])
```

Output would then be

```
apple
```

This is quite an old questions but I hope this answered the question simply.