# What is the Error "but it has nothing to do with the score, but with a list in a db" in Python (data base)

Tags: python, database, discord.py

I'm trying to create a discord bot command to display a list from a data base, but after watching a video to learn how to do it and (to make sure everything works) copying a piece of code, I get a "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "ObservedList") to list" error, and I don't understand what that means...

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMZjx.png)

the code :

```
import discord
import os
import json
import random
from replit import db

client = discord.Client()



insulte_ = [
  "fdp",
   "pd", 
   "con", 
   "chier"
  ]


def update_insulte(nouvelle_insulte):
  if "insulte" in db.keys():
    insulte = db["insulte"]
    insulte.append(nouvelle_insulte)
    db["insulte"] = insulte
  else:
    db["insulte"] = [nouvelle_insulte]


def delete_insulte(index):
  insulte = db["insulte"]
  if len(insulte) > index:
    del insulte[index]
    db["insulte"] = insulte


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Je me suis lancé en {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  #score = 30

  msg = message.content

  """if msg.startswith('$cs hello'):
    await message.channel.send('hello!')


  if msg.startswith('$cs cs'):
    await message.channel.send('vous avez ' + str(score))"""

  options = insulte_
  if "insulte" in db.keys():
    options = options + db["insulte"]


  if any(word in msg for word in options):
    await message.channel.send('vous avez perdu 10 crédits.')
    #score = score - 10


  if msg.startswith("$cs new"):
    nouvelle_insulte = msg.split("$cs new ",1)[1]
    update_insulte(nouvelle_insulte)
    await message.channel.send("nouvelle insulte ajoutée")


  if msg.startswith("$cs del"):
    insulte = []
    if "insulte" in db.keys():
      index = int(msg.split("cs del",1)[1])
      delete_insulte(index)
      insulte = db["insulte"]
    await message.channel.send(insulte)


  if msg.startswith("$cs insultes"):
    await message.channel.send(str(options))

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `options + db["insulte"]`

options is a list, db["insulte"] is an `ObservedList`.  You cannot just concatenate them together.

I think you want:

```
options + db["insulte"].value
```

As per this related question [How does my list become ObservedList? Problem with replit db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67265188/how-does-my-list-become-observedlist-problem-with-replit-db)

Comment: oh thx, this work, but now, when I delete an "insulte" with $cs del, firstly it takes away credits, so I'll have to find a way for it to take into account discord roles (a kind of whitelist of people who can insult), and secondly, an error appears telling me : "index = int(msg.split("cs del",1)[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' nike' ", nike being an insult I just added to the db with $cs new.